# Can't read CSV file with R script

Tags: r, csv

I'm still very new to R and I'm trying to read a moderate-size .csv file with a Script, but the script is unable to detect the file.

My code is at follows:

```
Saint<- read.csv("./Comp1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Saint
```

I have attempted several ways to indicate the file path. Including

```
path<- file.path("desktop", "saint", "Comp1.csv"
```

Then using the path variable in the read.csv function.

Also explicitly indicating the full path with forward slashes

It always throws the following error

```
> Saint<- read.csv("./Comp1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file './Comp1.csv': No such file or directory
> 
> Saint
Error: object 'Saint' not found
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Comment: it may help to try `getwd()` Just so you are clear what working directory you are in. And `dir()` to check the file is indeed there. If so `read.csv("Comp.csv")` will suffice.

Comment: I think your file paths are incorrect. If you want to access files in the containing directory you would use `../Comp1.csv`, i.e. two dots `..`. To access files from the desktop you first have to move through the hierarchy, i.e. `../../../../Desktop`, or just use the root directory `~/Desktop/saint/Comp1.csv`. My suggestions apply to Unix specifically, but the principle should apply to any system, i.e. you can't arbitrarily access directories simply by naming them.

Comment: Your path must be wrong. Run `list.files()` to see what R things is in the current directory. use `file.choose()` to be able to click on the file to get it's fill name. If R says the file doesn't exist, it's probably not lying.

Comment: try this: `Saint <- read.table(choose.files(),  stringsAsFactors = F ,  sep = ",", row.names = 1, na.strings = "#NUM!", comment.char ="")`  @Dasphillipbrau

Comment: So the solution by Stephen helped. The problem was that the script was not located (or reading from) the location where I thought it was. This is pretty strange, how does R defines its working directory? One would assume it does it based on where the script is saved.